# The argument number variable does not count the inputed parameters

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the following script :

```
echo  'Please select type file , the name of the input file and the name of the output file:

     a.plain ( please press a ) <input_file> <output_file>;
     b.complex ( please press b ) <input_file> <output_file>;'

read one two three
echo $#

if  [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
   echo "Insufficient arguments !"
   exit 1;
else
   echo "Number of passed parameters is ok"
fi
```

`$#` always outputs 0 , the read command provides the correct variables when I am using $one , $two and $three later in the script

Thank you.

Comment: A shell script must start with a `#!` line. If it's missing the kernel will refuse to execute the script. (There are shells which detect this error and attempt to work around it, but they aren't consistent about which interpreter to use. So you'll end up with very inconsistent behavior.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To test whether you got values for all variables and exit otherwise, use the `-z` test to test for empty strings:

```
if [ -z "$one" ] || [ -z "$two" ] || [ -z "$three" ]; then
    echo 'Did not get three values' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

The `$#` value is the number of *positional parameters*, usually command line arguments (or values set by the `set` builtin).  These are available in `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc. (or collectively in the array `"$@"`) and are unrelated to the values read by the `read` builtin.

---

To make your script take the input as command line arguments instead of reading them interactively (which may be preferred if the user is to supply one or several paths as they may take advantage of tab-completion, and it also makes it easier to use the script from within another script and does not require that there is a terminal connected), use

```
if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then
    echo 'Did not get three command line arguments' >&2
    exit 1
fi

one=$1
two=$2
three=$3
```

The script would in this case be run as

```
./script.sh a.plain /path/to/inputfile /path/to/outputfile
```

---

If the processing of the input can happen from standard input and if the output can be sent to standard output (i.e. if you don't actually *need* the explicit paths of the input file and output file inside the script), then the script only has to take the first parameter (`a.plain` or `b.complex`).

```
./script.sh a.plain </path/to/inputfile >/path/to/outputfile
```

The script would then use the standard input and standard output streams for input and output (and consequently only has to check for a *single* command line argument).

This would make it possible to run the script with data piped in from another program, and it would also allow for further post-processing:

```
gzip -dc <file-in.gz | ./script.sh a.plain | sort | gzip -c >file-out.gz
```

Answer (score 4):

## What you are doing wrong

You are confusing input arguments (to the script, at startup), and user input, using read (at run time).

`$#` reports number of arguments at startup. e.g. for `./«script_name» 1 2 3`, when used in the script, it will return 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `set` command to re-set the positional arguments, overwriting the previous values. The `IFS` variable specifies the list of characters to be used as a separator, so you can also use that to parse CSV. Note that `set` is a builtin, so the usual syntax to override variables for single commands does not work, as variables specified before a command are a shorthand for the `env` command, which would set the environment for a subprocess.

`$#` is the number of positional arguments that currently exist.

```
$ read foo
a b c d e      
$ echo $foo
a b c d e
$ set -- $foo
$ echo $#
5
$ IFS=: set -- $foo                  # doesn't work
$ echo $#
5                                    # still got 5
$ IFS=:
$ set -- $foo
$ echo $#
1
```